# Adding a fragment to an array on a parent scrollview

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview

I need to add a MapView to an exception list so the scrollview does not scroll when the user touches the map view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <org.xxx.ScrollViewWithMap
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/base_scrollview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </org.xxx.ScrollViewWithMap>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In the base fragment the mapFragment is added through:

```
        LocationMapFragment locationMapFragment = new LocationMapFragment();
        locationMapFragment.setArguments(args);
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map_fragment, locationMapFragment).commit();
```

Now I need to add this view to an array in the ScrollViewWithMap, but how can I do this. In the base fragment 'locationMapFragment' returns null for getView() and I don't know how to access the scrollView from within the fragment.

[Edit:]
I did try to add the fragment on the onAttach, but view is still 'null':

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

    ScrollViewWithMap scrollview = (ScrollViewWithMap) activity.findViewById(R.id.base_scrollview);
    scrollview.addInterceptScrollView(this.getView());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use ViewTreeObserver:

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = yourView.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //add in list here

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks I will have a look. I have just implemented an transparent image overlay at the moment with a action recogniser, but that does not seem to work well with older version.